# WCF Ria Services returning complex objects with child lists

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

When I build my model to be returned by WCF RIA Services to silverlight, the list properties are not shown in the silverlight client.

Class:

```
public class Batch
{
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<BasicInfoModel> Accepted { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<BasicInfoModel> UnAccepted { get; set; }
}

public class Batch
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When in the client, it seems the Lists are not generated, for example, this is my loaded callback event:

```
private void Callback(LoadOperation<Batch> loadOperation)
{
     //there is no such property as `Accepted`
     var acceptedList = loadOperation.Entities.FirstOrDefault().Accepted;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, you've missed DataContract attribute, e.g.

```
[DataContract]
public class Batch
{
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<BasicInfoModel> Accepted { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<BasicInfoModel> UnAccepted { get; set; }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx